Convert text to dataframe following a pattern in python
I have a list of comments with the next structure and I need to convert them into a dataframe
  comments_text = ['The SSS XXX 3\n',
 'from NNNNN xxx – 20 abr. 2024\n',
 'aaaa! CC DASASD ssss, ddd ,dddddd.\n',
 'Version 3.4.9 XX\n',
 'AAAsss 5\n',
 'from RRRR – 9 abr. 2024\n',
 'Sssss ss ssss dasasd asd asdasdasdfggdfgdfg fdfdsdsffdwq wewqewqedfsdfsdfsd faasdasdasda asdfsdfds sd fdsfdsgs dgd  fsd fsdfdsfsdfsd.\n',
 'Version 3.4.7 SS\n']

For that I created a function that extracts the position of 'Version...' and from those positions I try to extract the rest of the comments. The function is this
import re

def extract_comments_info(comment_lines):
    # List of comments
    comments_info = []
    
    # Pattern to find the verion
    version_pattern = re.compile(r"Version \d+\.\d+\.\d+")
    
    # Find all pattern matches in comment lines
    version_positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(version_pattern, comment_lines)]
    
    # Loop to find comments
    for pos in version_positions:
        # Obtain the version
        version_match = version_pattern.search(comment_lines, pos)
        version = version_match.group(0)
        
        # Obtain tittle, author and content
        title_start = comment_lines.rfind("'", 0, pos)
        title_end = pos - 2
        title = comment_lines[title_start + 1 : title_end]
        
        author_start = comment_lines.rfind("'", 0, title_start)
        author_end = title_start - 2
        author = comment_lines[author_start + 1 : author_end]
        
        content_start = comment_lines.rfind("'", 0, author_start)
        content_end = author_start - 2
        content = comment_lines[content_start + 1 : content_end]
        
        # Agg the information to the list of comments
        comments_info.append({
            'title': title,
            'author': author,
            'content': content,
            'version': version
        })
    
    return comments_info

Using the function:
comments_info = extract_comments_info(comments_text)
for comment in comments_info:
    print(comment)

this is the result and it works. But I'm looking for a better way to do it (if it's possible), since for a larger set of data it takes quite a while

